# fun with sequence

Tags: haskell

I have a set of five functions, that could be called one of five ways. I'm expressing that with patern-matching like so,

```
type Configure = ReaderT Config IO ()
data Step = PreVal
          | PreProc
          | Proc
          | PostProc
          | PostVal

foo :: Step -> Configure
foo PreVal = do some stuff
foo PreProc = do some stuff
```

and so on `bar` and `baz` are set up similarly

I know how to use `sequence` to call a list of actions. Given a `[Step]`, how could I go about calling `[foo,bar,baz]`. in sequence, while also calling each possible step.

so it should do this
`foo PreVal`
`foo PreProc`
... and so on
`bar Preval`
`bar PreProc`
.. and so on
`baz` ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
mapM_ (\ f -> mapM_ f [PreVal, PreProc, Proc, PostProc, PostVal]) [foo, bar, baz]
```

Answer (score 2):

I would like to add something to the previous answers.
As long as the order of your value constructors is the same as the order of execution of the steps, you could specify `deriving (Enum)`. This would allow you to write the list of all `Step`s as `[PreVal..PostVal]` and shorten the code.

Furthermore, consider a case in which you add a step before `PreVal` or after `PostVal`. To be sure that your calls consider the newly introduced step, you would better define an instance for `Bounded` too, and then use `minBound` and `maxBound` in the code.

Comment: Shortens, and removes one more place where changes would have to be made, in the event I add a Step. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

```
doThemAll steps = sequence_ $ do
    f <- [foo, bar, baz]
    step <- steps
    return (f step)
```

Comment: Alternatively: ```sequence_ $ [foo, bar, baz] `ap` steps``` (or with `<*>` instead of `ap`)